# angular2 client unable to handle large streamed response from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, angular, observable

I have an angular2 client HTTP request being thrown to a node.js server which is fetching a huge collection(~ 2 Million documents) from MongoDB and sending it as streamed response to the client.

Problem: works fine when the collection is small.but with a large collection, the client shows JSON parse errors.

Server side excerpt:

```
var first = true;
res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
res.write('"data" : [');
var stream = Datasource.db.collection(*collectionName*).find(*filterJson*).stream();

        stream.on('data', function(doc) {
            var prefix = first ? '' : ', ';
            res.write(prefix + JSON.stringify(doc));
            console.log(prefix +JSON.stringify(doc));
            first = false;
        });
        stream.on('end', function() {
            res.write(']}');
            console.log(']}');
            res.end();
        });
```

client side err :

```
  SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Response.Body.json (http.umd.js:777)
at MapSubscriber.eval [as project] (datasources.services.ts:28)
at MapSubscriber._next (map.ts:75)
at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.ts:95)
at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (http.umd.js:1180)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:275)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.umd.js:3971)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:274)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:151)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:345)
```

Here the snapshot of chrome's debugging tool:

[image]

How can I make my client listen for any amount of streamed response. Can I increase response time somehow.? I tried doing response.timeout = 300000 sec., but no help.

Comment: Did you ever get this worked out?